# Python: function parameters as a tuple with single output

Tags: python, tuples, parameter-passing

I have a function in Python which calculates the entropy of a number of parameters which I call `ps` as follows

```
def H(*ps): 
    sum = 0.0
    for pi in ps:
        sum = sum - pi*np.log2(pi)
    return sum
```

I want to be able to pass in multiple parameters as a list or tuple, i.e. `H([x])` but this doesn't give the correct result, rather it calculates the value of `H(xi)` and returns a tuple with each result. I am able to sum each element of the tuple to get the correct result due to the nature of the function but I'd rather be able to have the function give the desired output for convenience. If I enter `H(x1, x2, ...)` the function gives the correct output.

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Sample input and output:

```
x = [0.1, 0.2]
print H(0.1, 0.2), H(x)

0.796578428466 [ 0.33219281  0.46438562]
```

Comment: Please add sample input and output

Comment: @TaohidulIslam Updated

Comment: Alternatively, you can unpack `x` in `H(x)` with `H(*x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't unpack via the `*` operator in your function definition. You are already iterating your list via your `for` loop. It's natural to use an iterable as a function argument.

```
def H(ps): 
    x = 0.0
    for pi in ps:
        x = x - pi*np.log2(pi)
    return x

res = H([0.1, 0.2])

print(res)
0.796578428466
```

In addition, don't shadow the built-in `sum`, this is poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the argument as a `list` or `tuple`. You can avoid using unpack trick here.

```
def H(ps): #updated, not asterisk 
    my_sum = 0.0
    for pi in ps:
        my_sum = my_sum - pi*np.log2(pi)
    return my_sum
x = [0.1, 0.2]
print (H([0.1, 0.2])) #argument as list
print(H(x)) #argument as list
```